# Grails Spring Security creating account that's not in bootstrap.groovy

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-orm

By default Spring Security gives you three domain classes User, Role, and UserRole. I can easily make accounts in my bootstrap.groovy file in Grails 2.4.4 doing this

```
User admin = new User(username:'admin', password:'secret', enable:true, accountExpired:false, accountLocked:false, passwordExpired:false).save();
Role a = new Role(authority:'ROLE_ADMIN').save()
UserRole.create(admin, a);
```

but how in the world do you create one when in the session?

I have made classes that extend User, Role, and UserRole. I am able to save a new Role and a User, but I'm not able to save the relationship between them.

I realize this must have something to do with UserRole.create instead of save that User and Role use, I can't find any documentation on it because everyone just uses Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. If you run s2-quickstart you cannot use the relation domain class for anything. Say we make three classes User, Role, and UserRole. UserRole is only good for its methods. If you make a class that extends User, in my case SystemUser we can map the role to System user like so...

```
class SystemUser extends User
{

static belongsTo = [role:Role]

static constraints = {}

}
```

Then if we run a 'generate-all' for the SystemUser class we then modify the controller for SystemUser in the save section. Right under where the Instance is saved, you can easily assign a role. The code that assigns the user role is the key. You can then put the Roles in the boot strap or in the app.

```
 def save(SystemUser systemUserInstance) {
    if (systemUserInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (systemUserInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond systemUserInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    systemUserInstance.save flush:true

    //The code that assigns the Users Roles
    Role b = systemUserInstance.role;
    UserRole.create(systemUserInstance,b);

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'systemUser.label', default: 'SystemUser'), systemUserInstance.id])
            redirect systemUserInstance
        }
        '*' { respond systemUserInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what the problem you are having is, but here is how I am doing it:

```
def userRole = Role.findByAuthority(params.userRole)
def newUser = New User(params)

if(newUser.save()){
            agency.addToUsers(newUser)
            UserRole.create newUser, userRole, true
}
```

The extra boolean is just whether or not I want to a flush on the save.  If the user doesn't save properly then I render a page indicating such.

Comment: This is exactly what I said I wasn't looking for. I don't want it in bootstrap. I can generate views and save User and Role, but not UserRole. UserRole requires a create method. I can't call this method in any of my controllers or domain classes. It only allows it's own instance....Idk how to do that.

Comment: That code is direct from one of my controllers where I did the same thing.   The code in the bootstrap and the code in your controller should be pretty much the same; perhaps you can update your question with the some code that you have tried and the errors you are getting.

Comment: I wish I could just show code and update, but there's too many errors for doing such a simple thing. Maybe I'm not explaining clearly. I use s2-quickstart to generate User, Role, and UserRole as Domain classes. I then use 'generate-all' to make Controllers for each domain class. I can create Users and Roles in this way. However, I can't assign the User to a role in UserRole. I have to call the create method for UserRole. I try doing it inside the UserRole controller where it saves, but I'm unsuccessful. I get an error where I can't use that instance. Then I've tried calling it everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

Enter this code to bootstrap and it'll be work:

```
if (!Role.count()) {
    new Role(authority: Role.AvailableRoles.ADMIN.value()).save()
}
if (!User.findByEmail("admin@admin.com")) {
    User admin = new User(email: "admin@admin.com", password: "admin", enabled: true, firstName: 'Cool', lastName: 'Admin').save()
    def roleSystemAdmin = Role.findByAuthority(Role.AvailableRoles.ADMIN.value())
    if (!UserRole.findByUserAndRole(admin, roleSystemAdmin)) {
        UserRole.create(admin, roleSystemAdmin, true)
    }
}
```

Never forgot about if(), that exclude errors with duplicate values

Comment: This is exactly what I said I wasn't looking for. I don't want it in bootstrap. I can generate views and save User and Role, but not UserRole. UserRole requires a create method. I can't call this method in any of my controllers or domain classes. It only allows it's own instance....Idk how to do that.

Comment: Are you generate this domains by s2-quickstart?

Comment: Yeah, not only am I doing that I am using the 'generate-all' command for all three classes. I want to be able to create Users and Roles inside the app and assign them to UserRole. I make a UserRole controller through 'generate-all' but I'm unable to modify the domain class or controller to Assign the User to the Role in UserRole.

Comment: for what? You just need to do s2-quickstart User Role. And all should be work fine

Comment: No. s2-quickstart just creates domain classes, it doesn't actually put Users and Roles into the app and assign them. You have to make it happen in the boot strap, but what if you want it in a table instead? Then I create controllers for all three of the domain classes generated from s2-quickstart. Then I runApp, inside of the app I am able to make a new user...for sake of simplicity lets call him 'user' and I can make a role 'admin', however I cannot assign 'user' the 'admin' role. The problem lies in the UserRole association domain class in the controller.

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to associate User and Role withut UserRole. If yes: read spring security plugin documentation, its possible and simple. If not, please explain more

Comment: I've solved it with my own coding, they have horrible documentation.

Comment: Hope that you'll haven't some bugs in the future